# Looping an array then display the Odd and Even values in each arrays

Tags: arrays, loops

So I have this problem.

```
Input # of rooms: 4
room1:6
room2:4
room3:7
room4:3
```

(if I type 5 in "Input # of rooms" there would also be room5)

```
Odd: 7 3
Even: 6 4
```

I have to display the odd and even numbers, so I came up with this code:

```
System.out.print("Input # of rooms: ");
int rms=Integer.parseInt(io.readLine());

int[] array=new int[rms];
int a=0;
int b=1;


do {

    System.out.print("room "+b+":");
    array[a] = Integer.parseInt(io.readLine());
    a++;
    b++;

} while (a<rms);
```

I don't know how to display which are Odd numbers and which are Even numbers?

Comment: I take it you're using Java?

Answer (score 5):

you want to find the remainder or modulus when the param is divided by 2.

3 % 2 = 1 so odd
4 % 2 = 2 so even

```
if(param % 2 == 1){
  Print odd number
}else{
  Print even number
}
```

Should get you started

Answer (score 1):

The use of the modulo operator (`%`) will be invaluable here  - it performs integer division and returns the remainder of the quotient - kind of like short division.

The rules for determining the type of number are simple:

- If the number is *even*, it is divisible by 2.
- Otherwise, it is *odd*.

As for the printing part:  I would recommend accumulating the values in two separate `StringBuffer`s or `String`s if you prefer, adding a space between when we get another of the type of value we want.  Then, we can print it out pretty after we're done iterating through the array.

One last thing - you should only need one loop - preferably a `for` loop, since you know exactly how many elements you're going to iterate over.  You can use the above rules for modulus to determine which number gets appended to which variable.